# How can liquids be two temperatures in different spots?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity, convection

How come water can be two temperatures at different 'spots' after adding colder water to hot water? The density and viscocity is the same, so what makes them be seperate temperatures in seperate places for a few seconds rather than spreading out immediately.

Obviously after a few seconds the cold water spreads and lowers the temperature of the whole area of water (more or less).

Just curious here, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What's the alternative? You pour hot water into cold water, it would  be just as difficult,  even more so, to explain how the total water amount **immediately** came to the same temperature. The delay in the heat equalising is a reflection of the time it takes for the kinetic energy of the hot water molecules to spread to the colder areas.

Comment: as opposed to the cold water spreading more evenly and maybe faster

Comment: im not a scientist by any means just curious.

Comment: Curiosity is vital, no problem with that. Here is a longer version of how heat spreads http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_energy

Comment: look also for heat equation. The basic idea is that heat which is really molecular movement gets transferred by stochastic collisions which need time to spread - like a concentration profile in diffusion. Fourier's law and Fickian diffusion are thus mathematically the same and well - it just takes time for collisions to happen and for the effect to spread spatially.

Comment: Really density at different temperatures is the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can have spatial temperature variations for a while, and the time to reach a uniform temperature depends on how vigorously the fluids are mixed.  Just like in solids, heat is transferred in liquids by conduction, and, in addition, solids and liquids both have thermal inertia (heat capacity).  If mixing is absent, it takes a long time for heat to be conducted over longer distances from hot regions to cold regions, and the time to homogenize is long.  If the mixing is vigorous, small hot parcels of fluid are brought into intimate contact with small cold parcels of fluid, and the homogenization takes place much more rapidly.

Comment: So no convection in a liquid?

Comment: @Paparazzi If you are referring to natural convection, then yes, that is a kind of "passive mixing" present also.  However, the term mixing is more often considered a form of forced convection created by the motion of a moving boundary (e.g., a stirrer).

Comment: Mixing is not absent.   Heat transfer is not limited to conduction.

Comment: @Paparazzi Who said anything about mixing being absent?  The basic mechanism for convection is creating (by flow) thinner layers of hot and cold fluid for the heat to be conducted through.  Didn't they teach you this in your heat transfer course?

Comment: You said it "If mixing is absent, ".   Then you follow with conduction only.  Your stated answer ignores convection.

Comment: @Paparazzi Aah.  Natural convection mixing will be virtually absent if the fluid is extremely viscous.  I guess what I should have said was "if mixing were absent entirely, it would take a ....."

Comment: Water is not viscous.

Comment: @Paparazzi I was taking about fluids in general.  And water, of course, is viscous.

Answer (score 0):

> "The density and viscosity is the same"

No. They get changed with temperature.

In normal pressure-range (in-which ice doesn't get directly vaporized), if we increase temperature, the density normally decreases (water gets lighter) (However the "**water anomaly**" found in lower temperature  ... If we keep the pressure=1atm,  Water is densest at 4 degree C. below this temperature water again gets lighter.) Below or above this temperature, water become lighter.

For liquids (**not for gases**), increase of temperature ,usually cause decrease in viscosity. Because increased temperature means increased molecular vibrations. Increased-vibration will help molecules to escape from strong intermolecular attraction (for water, it is better known as "hydrogen-bonds").

> "Obviously after a few seconds the cold water spreads"

quite obvious, but it takes time too. If instead a drop of water-of-differen-temp. we put a drop of ink, the ink takes some time to get mixed totally.

A portion of water can transfer energy to a surrounding portion of water by 4 ways.

1. conduction,
2. convection
3. irradiation
4. direct mix-up of molecules.

But there requires "**time**" to complete these process, so, in a particular moment, you found spots of different different temperature. Also, within this-time, gravitation can separate spots of water of different temperature. (convection works only when water is heated from bottom). So in some cases gravitation resists the mix-up of portions of water having different temperature.

Some natural examples where convection doesn't help:

1. In ponds of warm-climate region (all temperature > 4C) , when sunrays warm the upper-layer of water, the lower (heavier) portion stays cold throughout day.
2. In cold-climates, in a frozen-lake, warmest (4C) deep down to bottom, and stays there . Any cooler (hence lighter) portion , say 2C, comes up, and warmer portion (say 3C) goes down to replace it.

So, **"time"** is the factor here.

Answer (score -1):

Different temperature water will not have the same density or viscosity.

There modes of heat transfer

- irradiation
- conduction
- convection

Since this is a fluid convection (mixing of the molecules) will be the primary heat transfer.  Followed by conduction.

Your statement of seconds is wrong unless this is a very small vessel.

I could not find numbers on diffusion rate (natural mixing) for water.  I do remember peeing the the pool as a kid and it did not dissipate as fast as I had hoped.  In perfectly still water it about 1 inch / second.  Certainly less than 1 foot / second.  You could easily test by dropping some dye in the water.  If the water is hotter then faster.

Just pouring the cold water in will introduce some forced mixing. The cold water will sink so that will introduce some mixing.